# Как сделать показ только английской клавиатуры в Андроид

Tags: android, клавиатура, android-softkeyboard

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы при открытии клавиатуры пользователь мог вводить только английские (латинские) символы и цифры без возможности смены языка.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Для уточнения, просто проверка на латиницу при вводе не подходит?

Comment: Один из альтернативных вариантов сделать собственную клавиатуру в своём приложение

Comment: @JackFromBB , вообще можно, а каким образом это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

как вариант

второй вариант

```
android:imeOptions="flagForceAscii"
```

из кода:

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_FORCE_ASCII);
```